# use closure_tree to represent ordered list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, list, rubygems

Would it be advisable to use the [`closure_tree`](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem to represent an ordered list? e.g. this Rails model:

```
class OrderedSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree, order: 'position' #order is a supported option
end
```

My thoughts:

- It might be convenient represent an ordered
  dictionary, since the gem can generate a hash tree.
- Maybe sometimes you just want a list of trees? Random example: a central strand of nerve cells in the arm with neurons that branch out along it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of `closure_tree`.

If you use the `append_sibling` or `prepend_sibling` methods that are added to your model class if the order column is numeric, your `position` value will be reordered from `0..siblings.count`. No need to use another gem—I had to rely on specific ordering rules to make the majority of scopes order correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the gem, I realized that it doesn't directly alter the order `position`, so it requires us to use our own functionality to set that column.

Basically: to represent a list, use the `acts_as_list` gem or another option. To use an ordered list in conjunction with the nodes of a tree, use both gems. (they should be compatible but I am not sure)